# Unable to show correct description corresponding to my image

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I'm using jquery cycle to display 20 images and i want to have a additional description for each of my image from my database. However, every time when I select, jquery show the correct image but row out 20 description for one image. Would appreciate if anyone can assist here. Thanks.

```
<script type="text/Javascript">

$('#prebox').cycle({ 
fx:     'fade', 
speed:  'fast', 
timeout: 0, 
pager:  '#nav', 
pagerAnchorBuilder: function(idx, slide) { 
    // return selector string for existing anchor 
    return '#nav li:eq(' + idx + ') a'; 
}     
}); 

</script>

<div id="prebox">
 <?php

      $sql1 = mysql_query ("SELECT * FROM espacepic WHERE email = 'jaychou@hotmail.com' AND storename='bill' "); 

        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql1))
        {
        $name = $row['name'];
        $name_array1[] = $name;
        $email = $row['email'];
        $name_array3[] = $email;
        }

       foreach($name_array1 as  $im1) 
       {  
        echo "<a href='#' ><img src='storepic/$im1' class='img11'  /></a>";
       }

       foreach($name_array3 as  $imm) 
       {  
        echo "$imm";
       }

 ?>

    </div>  
        <ul id="nav" >  

     <?php

      $sql2 = mysql_query ("SELECT * FROM espacepic WHERE email = 'jaychou@hotmail.com' AND storename='bill' "); 

        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql2))
        {
        $name = $row['name'];
        $name_array2[] = $name;
        }

        foreach($name_array2 as $im2) 
        {  
        ?>
         <li>
         <?php
         echo "<a href='#'><img src='storepic/$im2' width=73px height=68px /></a>";
         ?>
         </li>
         <?php
        }
       ?>

        </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are first printing all the images and then all the text. Shouldn't you print them in pairs...one image and one text? And probably put every pair in some container?